# Use highlightCallback to highlight in Synchronized graphs points with same 'x'

Tags: dygraphs

I'm successfully synchronizing several dygraph graphs on the zoom ranges (using zoomCallback and the updateOptions({dateWindow: new_range})).

I would like to synchronize also the highlights. When the user highlight one point (x,y) in one of the graphs, I would like to highlight all points with the same x in the other graphs.

Someone knows a way to do this?

In my particular case, each graph contains one serie only, and all series have the same x ranges.

Answer (score 1):

Set a `highlightCallback` and `unhighlightCallback` on each chart which calls `setSelection` on the others. See the dygraphs [options reference](http://dygraphs.com/options.html) and [API](http://dygraphs.com/jsdoc/symbols/Dygraph.html) for syntax.